# How to save an xarray.DataArray directly as a Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF?

Tags: python, rioxarray, xarray, cloud-optimized-geotiff

Is there a good way to produce a cloud-optimized GeoTIFF (https://www.cogeo.org) **directly** from an [`xarray.DataArray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/v2022.03.0/generated/xarray.DataArray.html)? At the moment it takes me a couple of steps to produce an intermediate regular GeoTIFF first, and run it through a converter like [`rio-cogeo`](https://cogeotiff.github.io/rio-cogeo) to turn it into a Cloud-Optimized GeoTIFF. Something like this:

#### Step 1: Produce regular non-cloud optimized GeoTIFF

```py
# https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/COG.html
import rioxarray
import xarray as xr

# Load Cloud-Optimized GeoTIFF into an xarray.DataArray
rds: xr.DataArray = rioxarray.open_rasterio(
    filename="https://oin-hotosm.s3.amazonaws.com/5d7dad0becaf880008a9bc88/0/5d7dad0becaf880008a9bc89.tif",
    masked=True,
    overview_level=4,
)

# Save output to a regular GeoTIFF
rds.rio.to_raster(raster_path="non-cogeo.tif")
```

#### Step 2: Convert regular GeoTIFF to cloud-optimized GeoTIFF

```bsh
rio cogeo create --cog-profile=zstd --forward-band-tags non-cogeo.tif cogeo.tif

rio cogeo info cogeo.tif
```

produces

```
Driver: GTiff
File: /home/username/projects/cogeo.tif
COG: True
Compression: ZSTD
ColorSpace: None

Profile
    Width:            688
    Height:           312
    Bands:            3
    Tiled:            True
    Dtype:            uint8
    NoData:           None
    Alpha Band:       False
    Internal Mask:    False
    Interleave:       PIXEL
    ColorMap:         False
    ColorInterp:      ('red', 'green', 'blue')
    Scales:           (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    Offsets:          (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

Geo
    Crs:              EPSG:3857
    Origin:           (-13334019.180693429, 4339530.742948703)
    Resolution:       (1.1943285669562078, -1.194328566956247)
    BoundingBox:      (-13334019.180693429, 4339158.112435812, -13333197.482639363, 4339530.742948703)
    MinZoom:          16
    MaxZoom:          17

Image Metadata
    AREA_OR_POINT: Area
    OVR_RESAMPLING_ALG: NEAREST

Image Structure
    COMPRESSION: ZSTD
    INTERLEAVE: PIXEL
    LAYOUT: COG

Band 1
    ColorInterp: red
    Metadata:
        STATISTICS_MAXIMUM: 255
        STATISTICS_MEAN: 85.125740720036
        STATISTICS_MINIMUM: 0
        STATISTICS_STDDEV: 52.508740750754
        STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT: 100

Band 2
    ColorInterp: green
    Metadata:
        STATISTICS_MAXIMUM: 255
        STATISTICS_MEAN: 86.283914728682
        STATISTICS_MINIMUM: 0
        STATISTICS_STDDEV: 49.498808560978
        STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT: 100

Band 3
    ColorInterp: blue
    Metadata:
        STATISTICS_MAXIMUM: 255
        STATISTICS_MEAN: 76.663461538462
        STATISTICS_MINIMUM: 0
        STATISTICS_STDDEV: 47.378616249492
        STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT: 100

IFD
    Id      Size           BlockSize     Decimation           
    0       688x312        256x256       0
    1       344x156        128x128       2
```

Is it possible to combine Steps 1 and 2 into one? I.e. not have to save to an intermediate file and just produce the cloud-optimized GeoTIFF directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```py
rds.rio.to_raster(raster_path="cogeo.tif", driver="COG")
```

https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/cog.html

Comment: Awesome, knew there had to be a simple way! Thanks @snowman2!